# How to uninstall feature without Feature.xml file?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, stsadm

I have feature which is not correctly installed on my website.
How can I uninstall it without Feature.xml file and without feature id?

Comment: We need a whole lot more information that this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather not. :D

The answer is here:

http://www.gilham.org/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=aab85845-88d2-4091-8088-a6bbce0a4304&ID=229

Firstly run the WssAnalyzeFeatures tool.
Next it will produce output file named: ContentDeploymentFeatures.txt.
Take appropriate feature id and run stsadm commands: deactivate and uninstall feature with id and force option.

And it's done! :D

Answer (score 1):

There [WssAnalizyFeatures](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WssAnalyzeFeatures) and [FeatureCleaner](http://thomascarpe.com/Blog%20Downloads/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=2) that might help you out.